# How to recompile Crypto++ with GCC-4.8?

Tags: compilation, freebsd, crypto++

My question is how can I recompile Crypto++ with GCC-4.8 in FreeBSD 9.2?

I'm having the following error, and I noticed that recompiling CrypTopp would solve the problem.

```
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate(void*)'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I recompile Crypto++ with GCC-4.8 in FreeBSD 9.2?

There's usually 3 or 4  things to be mindful of with later versions of GCC and the BSDs. They are enumerated below. If you have a specific problem, then you should ask.

### -----

First, install `gmake` and use it instead of the BSD's anemic `make`. So you would compile with something like:

```
cd cryptopp
gmake GNUmakefile
```

I think other dependencies include `gettext` and `libiconv`.

### -----

Second, the Crypto++ makefile sometimes blows away your choice of `CXX` and maybe `LD`. Open the `GNUmakefile` and hard code them to want you want if its occurring.

### -----

Third, Crypto++ has some bug fixes for dependent name lookups. This only affects later versions of GCC, like 4.7 or 4.8 and above. See, for example, [Unable to make on MingW due to unrecognized option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26963303/608639).

So you should be using Crypto++ from SVN, and ***not*** the ZIP file from the website. See [SVN](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SVN) on the Crypto++ wiki on how to check it out.

### -----

Fourth, install Crypto++ into `/usr/local`, and not `/usr`. For some reason, one of the BSDs (OpenBSD) treat everything in `/usr/include` as a C file, and does not honor a C++ file. It will lead to unexplained compile failures. You can read about it on the Crypto++ wiki: [Linux and OpenBSD](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux#OpenBSD).

So your install would look like:

```
sudo gmake install PREFIX=/usr/local
```

### -----

There should also be a port available. You should try and use it if its available. For example its available as [cryptopp-5.6.3-2](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/security/cryptopp/) under FreeBSD. OpenBSD has a patch at [Fix: net/synergy](http://openbsd.7691.n7.nabble.com/fix-net-synergy-td228522.html), so its probably available in their ports tree, too.

### -----

Finally, there is a Crypto++ wiki page covering Linux and the BSDs at [Linux and BSD](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux). Its basically everything I know about building and running Crypto++ on *nix variants. If you are a die hard BSD guy, then my apologies for lumping Linux and BSD together on one page.